Нумерация строк rich text box
Пишу свою версию С++. На данный момент закончил написание препроцессора.
Возникла потребность написать свой редактор для С++ (типо VS Code). Решил писать на C# WPF.
Я решил использовать rich text box. Проблема заключается в следующем: как сделать нумерацию строк в rich text box.
Если это не возможно сделать с помощью rich text box, то скажите каким способом это надо делать?

свой контрол писать, видимо, возможно на базе того же ричбокса

Что вы имеете в виду aepot?

Видимо, что такого встроенного функционала там нет. Нужно надстройку свою писать.

CrazyElf, можно про это по подробнее

Ну, WPF же это такие "строительные кубики", одни контролы построены из других контролов. И можно поверх стандартных контролов свой user control написать. Система удобная, но продумывать архитектуру своего контрола довольно непросто.

Попробую, CrazyElf, авось что получится

Ваша версия C++ будет чем-то глобально отличаться в синтаксисе от других? Если нет, то можете использовать любой существующий редактор C++. / А ещё посмотрите на Language Server Protocol (нагуглите сами). Описываете LSP для своего языка и получаете подсветку синтаксиса, автодополнение, рефакторинги и прочее во всех редакторах (IDE) поддерживающих этот протокол.

Посмотрите исходники других редакторов. Например, AvalonEdit. Наверняка можно найти и другие.

Взять AvalonEdit и не парить мозг. Вон SharpDevelop на нем основан вроде. Там и нумерация, и расцветки и подстветка, и вроде даже рисование. Вот правда не любит длинных строк, но так везде

Спасибо Alexandr Petrov и vitidev
